# How to avoid nvidia optimus syndrome?

Tags: ati, hardware, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I'll be buying new laptop in few days, and reading the nvidia optimus problems, I got really scared. 
I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, if laptop has nvidia optimus capable card, as for example GeForce GT 630M, does that mean that such laptop has optimus capability or that's only the case if it has Intel integrated card as well? For example, when looking at [laptops specifications](http://www.links.hr/?naziv=prijenosno-racunalo-asus-k93sm-yz171-pentium-b960-dvdrw-dl-4gb-1000gb-geforce-gt-630m-18-4-led-g-lan-bt-kamera-hdmi-usb-3-0-dos-crna&option=artikl&id_kategorija=01466005&id_artikl=014.660.019), I can't see intel card anywhere nor "optimus" key word, it confuses me. Obviously if only nvidia card was present then their card will work fine, but are there such cases where no intel card is present?
What about ATI, do they have some kind of equivalent technology that is not supported on Linux? If not, I'd be probably better of with ATI card.

Comment: Here is a good review of the current support in Linux: http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/17702